# QTableView игнорирует первый столбец и строку из модели представления

Tags: c++, qt, tableview, qtableview, model-view

дела обстоят так - в функцию `TableViewModel::populate` подаётся массив новых значений `QVector<QVector<CellData>> newValues` для записи в `QVector<QVector<CellData*>*>* TableViewModel::values`, из которых модель представления будет вытягивать информацию и отображать в `QTableView`. Проблема заключается в том, что в `QTableView` не отображается первая строка и первый столбец, отсчет `headerData` тоже начинается не с первого, а со второго элемента по строке и столбцу. Важно заметить, что при вызове `beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), -1, idx)` вместо `beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), 0, idx)` вылезает debug error (что неудивительно, ведь нельзя начинать вставлять ряды с минус первого), но - о чудо! Таблица отображается без всяких проблем с потерянными в случае с `beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), 0, idx)` первым рядом и столбцом. Я несколько раз менял структуру данных модели, но такая ошибка у меня впервые, до этого всё работало с `beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), 0, idx)`, с чем это может быть связано? Прилагаю код `TableViewModel::populate`.

```
void TableViewModel::populate(QVector<QVector<CellData>> newValues)
{
    QVector<QVector<CellData*>*> temp_values;

    for (int i = 0; i < newValues.count(); i++)
    {
        auto qstrvec = new QVector<CellData*>[newValues.count()];
        for (int j = 0; j < newValues.at(0).count(); j++) 
        {
            CellData old_cell = newValues[i][j];
            CellData* cell = new CellData(old_cell.getCellSpan());
            cell->setFormula(old_cell.getFormula());
            cell->setTextColor(old_cell.getTextColor());
            cell->setBackgroundColor(old_cell.getBackgroundColor());
            cell->setValue(old_cell.getValue());
            (*qstrvec).push_back(cell); 
        }
        temp_values.push_back(qstrvec);
    }
    auto rows = (*this->values).count();
    auto columns = (*(*this->values)[0]).count();
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
        {
            delete (*(*this->values)[i])[j];
        }
        delete[](*this->values)[i];
    }

    int idx = temp_values.count();
    this->beginInsertRows(QModelIndex(), 0, idx);
    *this->values = temp_values;
    this->endInsertRows();
 }
```

Comment: Тут много вопросов. Почему все по значению, а внутри что-то выделяется. Что вообще эта функция и этот класс делает делает. `newValues.at(0).count()` выглядит подозрительно - вы считает что у всех векторов тот же размер что и у нулевого. Судя по симптому -скорее  всего проблема в непоказанном коде. Например в делегате.

Comment: Насчет `newValues(0).count()` - у меня берется размер первой строки за базовый размер всех строк.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Я забыл упомянуть, что `values` у меня по итогу всех этих операций полностью копирует данные из подаваемого в `populate` `newValues` и не теряет данные по первым строке и ряду. Тогда я в полном замешательстве, ведь с последней версии проекта я ничего не менял в классе модели. А что я мог наделать такого с делегатом, не трогая этот класс, мне в голову не приходит.

Comment: Я так и не увидел здесь намека на связь с таблицей, моделью данных или чем либо.  Только метод который частично копирует что-то куда-то, (вроде бы), правильно.  За то, куда какие данные отображаются, отвечает `QAbstractTableModel::data`

Comment: В том-то и прикол, что в `QAbstractTableModel::data` у меня ничего не менялось в последней версии) то есть, оно теперь с ровно таким же массивом данных стало делать что-то другое. Весьма интересное поведение. Теперь дилемма - отключить виндовский дебаггер и пойти дальше по плану или сидеть и корпеть над этой недоошибкой, которая, вроде как, ничего плохого (пока) не делает.

Comment: звучит как эффект QSortFilterProxyModel - она может подменять индексы.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ был действительно в непоказанном коде. В `MainWindow` удалял предыдущую модель и не делал после этого `tableView->setModel(nullptr)`, что и вызывало такое странное поведение.